# How to get the property value from camel context in camel route

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am loading the property value from database.

`paraDetailsRepository.loadParaDetails(ParamConstants.KYC_API_VERSION);`

And, setting the value to a property map and assign to camel context

`properties.put("kyc.api.version.param", para.get(0));
 camelContext.setGlobalOptions(properties)`

I need to get the property value from camel context from camel route.

Can someone suggest a way to get the property value in camel route.

Thanks

```
protected SpringCamelContext camelContext;

@EventListener
public void loadParaDetails(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
        List<ParaDetails> paraDetails = paraDetailsRepository.loadParaDetails(ParamConstants.KYC_API_VERSION);

        for (ParaDetails para : paraDetails) {
            properties.put("kyc.api.version.param", para.get(0));
        }
        camelContext.setGlobalOptions(properties)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a Java route, you can use a `processor` where you can get hold of `CamelContext` where you can then call the getter for global options where you can then get the property you stored there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RouteBuilder to build your routes configure() method  you can use getContext() to get CamelContext.

```
CamelContext context = getContext();
```